# Finding I2C Slave Address For MT9P031 image sensor

Tags: fpga, i2c, datasheet, camera

Here is the datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MT9P031-D.PDF

On page 12 of the datasheet, it shows an example of I2C communication. The first byte sent is 0xBA. Is this the slave address of this image sensor?

Answer (score 1):

It depends: 0xBA is the write address, while 0xBB is the read address.